# Is RPA.Tables can have the same effect as PrettyTable for outputting a table display?

Tags: robotframework

I want to make a table with some results as output display on the Robot Framework. Currently, I have an example on Python with PrettyTable.

I try to duplicate from Python to Robot Framework, but it doesn't work. Could someone give me a suggestion?

Thank you.

Following is the script on the Robot Framework.

```
&{a}    Create Dictionary   aaa=111 bbb=222 ccc=333
&{b}    Create Dictionary   ddd=${a}        
${c}    RPA.Tables.Create Table data=${b}       
Log 111: ${c}
```

Following is the Python [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVufi.png)

2022_0104:
Hello all,
I just realized there's a workaround that can achieve what I mentioned. Please refer to the attached. Maybe it's not a good solution.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1gK4.png)